# How can i change the timezone without changing the time in moment timezone?

Tags: momentjs

How can i change the timezone without changing the date/time in moment / moment-timezone?

```
e.g 15/01/2016 09:00:00 +02:00
to e.g 15/01/2016 09:00:00 +00:00
```

I have tried the solution as posted in the following links [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593304/same-date-in-different-time-zone/28615654#28615654), however this relies on a utcOffset() function which moment complains as being deprecated.

Reading the thread there is an example which states something such as the following might work (but it does not) although i see where the author is going.

`moment.tz(moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"), "America/Los_Angeles")`

This complains of Invalid Date.

Comment: `utcOffset` is not deprecated.  What's deprecated is passing a string to the moment constructor (your `date` variable`) without specifying its format.

Comment: Also, you should never format a date to a string just to parse it back to an object again.  As I answered in the other question, you just mutate the exiting moment object by calling `.tz` on it, instead of `.utcOffset`.

Comment: Answered in the comments of the other question.  Voting to close as duplicate, since this question doesn't add anything significant.

Comment: I am unable to get that to do what it needs to. Calling .tz actually changes the time element. I simply want to change the 'zone' element.

Comment: You still have to shift it back, which is the very next line of code.  As I said in that answer, doing this shifting gives you a completely different moment in time, and is not recommended.

Comment: I've expanded my answer in the dup post.