# FullCalendar JS - select callback passes start and end dates in wrong timezone

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I was trying to insert selected event to DB and I noticed that time I select in calendar is different than passed to AJAX. `select` callback passes "start" and "end" dates with different timezones than the calendar is set to.

My calendar settings:

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, today, next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    timezone: 'Australia/Sydney',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
        var startDate = new Date(start);
        var endDate = new Date(end);
        console.log(startDate);
        console.log(startDate);

        // ajax to insert event to DB

    },
    // other configurations
});
```

Now my dumped `startDate` and `endDate` looks like:

```
Mon Nov 14 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Which is not `Australia/Sydney` that calendar is set to, so I am saving wrong start and end dates in DB. I kinda feel that this is problem with `new Date()` that generates given timestamp with default timezone and not the one that calendar is set to.

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: You might have to use UTC to adjust for any different region:  http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/ - you can also take a look at http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start and end dates are [moment](http://momentjs.com/) objects. They are no longer in the current time zone though, so you must clone the object, apply the time zone and add the offset difference.

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var startClone = start.clone();
    startClone.tz('Australia/Sydney');
    startClone.add(start.utcOffset() - startClone.utcOffset(), 'minutes');
    console.log(startDate.format());
}
```

Comment: I tried running this: `moment(start).tz('Australia/Sydney').format()` so now if I select from 7:00 to 8:00 it's not that moment assigns timezone to this hour, but instead converts 7:00 with that timezone which is 18:00. All I need that 7:00 would be `Australia/Sydney` timezone

Comment: I found how to shift time here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593304/same-date-in-different-time-zone/28615654#28615654 if you update your answer I will mark as correct, since you gave me the reight path to work with moment.

Comment: I have updated the answer to calculate the offset. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using `new Date()`.

`new Date()`, by default, operates on the browser timezone on which application is running, WITHOUT considering the timezone you are running in the app or the timezone that the user has set in the profile(if it's applicable in your case).

For multi-timezone applications, [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) are the best choice