# Set time zone of specific offset using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

My question is similar to [Same date in different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593304/same-date-in-different-time-zone), though I think about not using the momentjs to get the final unix time with same local time and different offset. Is plain javascript able to accomplish this ? With the input `18-02-2015 21:08:34 +01:00`
And result:

```
result2: 18-02-2015 21:08:34 +01:00
result3: 18-02-2015 21:08:34 +10:00
result4: 18-02-2015 21:08:34 +05:00
result5: 18-02-2015 21:08:34 -06:00
result6: 18-02-2015 21:08:34 -11:00
```